# How to calculate the total amount when checkbox is cheked and item added to cart?

Tags: angularjs

Here i have to calculate the total price when a product is checked and added into cart.How can i achieve this please help me?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="startCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="value(item.isSelected,x)"/>{{x.name}} {{x.price}}
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>Selected Item</div>
    <div ng-repeat="y in selectedItems" ng-show="selectedItems.length>0">
        {{y.name}}----{{y.price}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="selectedItems.length<=0"> No item selected </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("startCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.names=[{name:"mobile",price:"100"},{name:"Laptop",price:"200"},{name:"bag",price:"50"}];
        $scope.selectedItems=[];    
        $scope.value=function(isSelected,item){
            if(isSelected==true){
                $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
            }
            else {
                console.log(item.name);
                angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function(itemRmv,$index){
                    if(itemRmv.name==item.name)  {
                        $scope.selectedItems.splice($index,1);
                    }
                 })
            }
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like create a filter that will give you total price from `selectedItems`.
And then you can apply that filter on `selectedItems`.

**Filter**

```
app.filter('getprice', function () {
    return function (value, property) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(value, function (val, index) {
            total = total + parseInt(val.price)
        });
        return total;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="startCtrl">
        <div>Total Price {{selectedItems| getprice}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="value(item.isSelected,x)" />{{x.name}} {{x.price}}</div>
        <hr/>
        <div>Selected Item</div>
        <div ng-repeat="y in selectedItems" ng-show="selectedItems.length>0">{{y.name}}----{{y.price}}</div>
        <div ng-show="selectedItems.length<=0">No item selected</div>
    </div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13381/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much .its exactly fulfilled my requirement.

Comment: @Sujithrao Could you tell me why you unmarked my answer? Do you think it is not good answer?

Comment: I believe filter is reusable code and it is loosely coupled with logic.

Comment: I used filter only here in my programe. sorry by mistake its unmarked

Comment: .could you please help me i have one more small amendment here in this code

Comment: @Sujithrao  what is the issue?

Comment: How to get the additional price from some other controller and add to this total price?

Comment: @Sujithrao then your `<div>Total Price {{(selectedItems| getprice}}</div>` will be look like `<div>Total Price {{(selectedItems| getprice)} + (selectedItems1| getprice)}</div>` assuming `selectedItems1` will contain second selected item list

Comment: i tried like {{selectedItems | getprice}} + {{y.MenuPrice}} but it giving the out put as something like 20 + 100.its not calculating total?

Comment: don't do like this..it should be `{{(selectedItems | getprice) + y.MenuPrice}}` MenuPrice should be an integer, otherwise you need to convert is manually

Comment: i used to parse like this {{ (selectedItems | getprice) + parseInt(y.MenuPrice)}} but its not working?.could you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the string values for price in your name array with integer values, then you can keep a total value when you add and remove items

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="startCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="x in names">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="value(item.isSelected,x)"/>{{x.name}} {{x.price}}
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>Selected Item</div>
    <div ng-repeat="y in selectedItems" ng-show="selectedItems.length>0">
        {{y.name}}----{{y.price}}
    </div>
    <div>{{total}}</div>
    <div ng-show="selectedItems.length<=0"> No item selected </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("startCtrl",function($scope){
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.names=[{name:"mobile",price:100},{name:"Laptop",price:200},{name:"bag",price:50}];
        $scope.selectedItems=[];    
        $scope.value=function(isSelected,item){
            if(isSelected==true){
                $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
                $scope.total += item.price;
            }
            else {
                $scope.total -= item.price;
                console.log(item.name);
                angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function(itemRmv,$index){
                    if(itemRmv.name==item.name)  {
                        $scope.selectedItems.splice($index,1);
                    }
                 })
            }
        } 
    });

</script>
```